# a place filled/filling with fun

Tags: past-participles, present-participles, participial-adjectives

Is there any practical difference between "filling" and "filled" in the following?

> John was staying at a place **filled**/**filling** with fun.

Comment: Both choices are confusing.  Could you provide the full context which includes the preceding sentences and the following sentences? Fun has multiple definitions, but they *usually* don't apply to a place, as much as they apply to people, or activities, or events.  "filling with fun" is especially unusual, as you seem to be strongly applying fun to a location, instead of people or activities.

Comment: As an instance of metonymy, "fun" might refer to fun activities.